# set specific cron job time from admin

Tags: magento2

i want to create configuration from admin for this cron tab how we can do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="order_product_report">
        <job name="order_product_report" instance="abc\abc\Cron\OrderReport" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your vendor name is `Imt`, and your module name is `OrderProductReport`.

Step 1: Create system.xml to add config in the system configuration:

- File path: app/code/Imt/OrderProductReport/etc/admin/system.xml
- Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="imt" translate="label" sortOrder="900">
            <label>IMT</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="imt" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                 showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Order Product Report</label>
            <tab>imt</tab>
            <resource>Imt_OrderProductReport::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="frequency" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Frequency</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Imt\OrderProductReport\Model\Config\Backend\OrderProductReportCron</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="time" translate="label" sortOrder="2" type="time" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Start Time</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create backend model class for Cron config.

- File path: app/code/Imt/OrderProductReport/Model/Config/Backend/OrderProductReportCron.php
- File content:

```
<?php

namespace Imt\OrderProductReport\Model\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Backend\Product\Alert;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class OrderProductReportCron extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/order_product_report/schedule/cron_expr';

    const CRON_MODEL_PATH = 'crontab/default/jobs/order_product_report/run/model';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory
     */

    protected $configValueFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */

    protected $runModelPath = '';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param string $runModelPath
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ValueFactory $configValueFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        $runModelPath = '',
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->runModelPath = $runModelPath;
        $this->configValueFactory = $configValueFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        $time = $this->getData('groups/general/fields/time/value') ?:
            explode(
                ',',
                $this->_config->getValue(
                    'imt/general/time',
                    $this->getScope(),
                    $this->getScopeId()
                ) ?: '0,0,0'
            );
        $frequency = $this->getValue();

        $cronExprArray = [
            (int)($time[1] ?? 0), //Minute
            (int)($time[0] ?? 0), //Hour
            $frequency == \Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency::CRON_MONTHLY ? '1' : '*', //Day of the Month
            '*', //Month of the Year
            $frequency == \Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency::CRON_WEEKLY ? '1' : '*', //Day of the Week
        ];

        $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);

        try {
            $this->configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $cronExprString
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_STRING_PATH
            )->save();
            $this->configValueFactory->create()->load(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH,
                'path'
            )->setValue(
                $this->runModelPath
            )->setPath(
                self::CRON_MODEL_PATH
            )->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('We can\'t save the cron expression.'));
        }

        return parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

Step 3: Set config path for crontab.xml.

- File path: app/code/Imt/OrderProductReport/etc/crontab.xml
- Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="order_product_report">
        <job name="order_product_report" instance="Imt\OrderProductReport\Cron\OrderReport" method="execute">
            <config_path>crontab/default/jobs/order_product_report/schedule/cron_expr</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

My code follows how Magento core has done in the Magento_ProductAlert module.

You can read more about system.xml reference from Magento document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/files/config-reference-systemxml.html

Answer (score 0):

In crontab.xml file you need to mention reference path of your store config field

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="order_product_report" instance="abc\abc\Cron\OrderReport" method="execute">
            <config_path>sectionName/groupname/fieldname</config_path>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: <config_path>sectionName/groupname/fieldname</config_path> how its come i mean system can you provide more code

Answer (score 0):

In your abc/abc/etc/system.xml you should add a field for the expression configuration:

```
<field id="cron_exp" translate="label comment" sortOrder="0" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Cron Expression</label>
</field>
```

Above should go inside a section and a group (assuming you already have those for other configurations).
In your crontab.xml you should point to that new configuration path:

```
    <job name="order_product_report" instance="abc\abc\Cron\OrderReport" method="execute">
        <config_path>sectionName/groupname/cron_exp</config_path>
    </job>
```